# Need Optimization & Performance related to Django ORM Query

Tags: python, sql, django, json, django-orm

I am writing an API in django 1.4.5 which return JSON data to third party application.

This is my current method to retrieve data but it takes more time because i also need related data to be available in JSON.

```
def get_speakers(request)
     speakers = Person.objects.filter(profile__person_type__name='Speaker').select_related('series')
     for speaker in speakers:
         data['first_name'] = speaker.first_name
         data['last_name'] = speaker.last_name
         data['series_name'] = speaker.series.name
         data['series_id'] = speaker.series.id
     return JSONResponse(data_dict)
```

To achieve optimization i tried as following.

```
def get_speakers(request)
     speakers = Person.objects.filter(profile__person_type__name='Speaker').select_related('series')
     data_dict = serializers.serialize("python", speakers)
     return JSONResponse(data_dict)
```

But it returns foreign key for related data in JSON which is useless because i can't get its related data.

Also it try for raw sql then data return in tuple but we need in dictionary format.

Need help to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would use the following.

```
def get_speakers(request)
     speakers = Person.objects.filter(profile__person_type__name='Speaker').values('first_name', 'last_name', 'series__name', 'series__id')
     return JSONResponse(speakers)
```

In django ORM, while naming fields only one underscore `_` is used. Since two underscore has another usage. In your example series is a foreign key, and if you would like to reach its fields while filtering and getting values, you could use like `'series__name'` to get name field of related record.

Besides [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) method there is [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method. You could use which is best for you.

Comment: Thanks alot.. :) I was struggling with prefetch_related to achieve the same. Thanks Again.